# Restore incorrect syntax near 'dbname'

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssms

I'm trying to restore a db to a new location, using the following in SQL Server Management Studio for Server2012:

```
RESTORE [newdb-name] FROM DISK = '..\backupfile.bak'
WITH MOVE 'olddb-name.mdf' to '...\newdb-name.mdf',
MOVE 'olddb-name_log.ldf' to '..\newdb-name_log.ldf';
GO
```

I'm getting the error "Incorrect syntax near 'newdb-name'" on line 1. Management studio isn't flagging it as a syntax error before running, and as the name has a hyphen I need to bracket it. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the word DATABASE, as in RESTORE DATABASE.

Comment: Almost want to delete the question because it's such a simple thing but I'm sure I'm not the first or last to trip on this.

Comment: @whybull yeah, I guarantee you other folks are gonna run into this, heh.